# Redirect post on click to a file - tumblr

Tags: tumblr

Noob here!!

I was setting up my photography blog on Tumblr and decided to make them available under public domain similar to unsplash. Tumblr's compression reduces the picture quality so thought i would link them to a high quality picture served out of my dropbox.

How can i create such a post wherein i can link a picture of mine as a Tumblr post with a thumbnail of the image but be able to redirect to the dropbox file on click?

I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work

```
{block:Link}
{block:Thumbnail}
<img src="{Thumbnail}" alt="{Name}">
{/block:Thumbnail}
{/block:Link}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `target` attribute:

```
{block:Link}
    <a href="{Target}" target="_blank">
        {block:Thumbnail}
             <img src="{Thumbnail}" alt="{Name}">
        {/block:Thumbnail}
    </a>
{/block:Link}
```

More info: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#link-posts